# How to create customFilter using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my 'AngularJS' application, I have filtered a list of record using `$first` and `$last` in `angularjs`. But unable to filter **$first row of first element** inside ng-repeat directive and **$last row of last element**  inside ng-repeat directive.

How to do this like., **ng-if="$first** *some filter condition***"**.

I have created a [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXmhFv8VNHMlD8fL6Ij7?p=preview).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
  
<meta name="description" content="[groupBy example]"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Groupby</title>
  <style>
  #ul li{list-style:none;}
  #ul li ul li{ padding: 5px 0px;float:left;width: 100px;}
  .clear{clear:both;float:none}
  .list{font-size:12px;color:gray;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;width: 150px;}
  
  first1 ul li{display:none}
  last1 ul li{display:none}
 .first1 ul li:first-child{background: orange;display:block}
 .last1 ul li:last-child{background: orange;display:block}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainController">   
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in batchs | groupBy: 'classId'" >
  <b>{{ key }}</b><br />
  .......
  <!--Filtered row -->
  <ul id="ul">
  <li>
  <ul>
  <li>Start Time</li><li>End Time</li>       
  </ul>
  </li>
  <p class="clear"></p>
  <li ng-repeat="batch in value"  ng-class="{'first1': $first, 'last1': $last}" ng-if="$first || $last">
  <ul>
  <li>{{ batch.inTime }}</li><li>{{ batch.outTime }}</li>       
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <!--/Filtered row -->
  <!--Complete row -->
  <ul id="ul" class="list">
  list of data
  <li ng-repeat="batch in value" >
  <ul>
  <li>{{ batch.inTime }}-{{ batch.outTime }}-{{ batch.teacher }}</li>        
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <!--/Complete row -->
  .......
  </div>
</div>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
var app=angular.module('app',['angular.filter']);
  app.controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
  $scope.batchs = [
    {Id:1, classId:'BCA',  inTime:10.00, outTime:11.00,teacher:'Alex'},
    
    {Id:4, classId:'MCA',  inTime:10.00, outTime:11.00,teacher:'Andrew'},
    {Id:5, classId:'MCA',  inTime:11.00, outTime:12.00,teacher:'Andrew'},
    
    {Id:6, classId:'M.Com',inTime:10.00, outTime:11.00,teacher:'William'},
    {Id:7, classId:'M.Com',inTime:11.00, outTime:13.00,teacher:'William'},
    {Id:8, classId:'M.Com',inTime:14.00, outTime:16.00,teacher:'William'}
  ];
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see the plnkr or run code snippet, i want to show only **orange** background time,like **first element start time** and **last element of end time**.

Ofcourse i have done this by using `css`. but i want to do this by `angularjs`.

How can i do this, Any suggestion or help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, You can create custom filters.

```
 angular.module('myCustomFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
      return function(input) {
        return input ? true :false ;
      };
    });
```

Now you created a filter called **checkmark**,
The input evaluates to either true or false, and we return true or false.

Now that our filter is ready, we need to register the **myCustomFilters** module as a dependency for our main app module.
Say, in app/js/app.js:

example

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myAppControllers','myCustomFilters']);
```

Since the filter is in a septate js file , Say ,**js/filters.js** , we need to include this file in our layout template.

```
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
```

Now you can use this filter everywhere  as

```
<div>{{UserStatus | checkmark}}</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is way too generic an answer and does not directly answer the question asked.